# Preventing accidental Git clone of origin

Tags: git

How can I prevent a team member from accidentally cloning "in the wrong direction"?

We recently ran into an issue when a new team member clobbered origin by cloning local instead of cloning origin.  Yeah, we were able to recover.  However I'd like to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: How did that "clobber origin"?

Comment: Whatever you clone from becomes the origin. Are you saying the origin was wrong?

Comment: @meagar How? As in it was unusable.  I don't have first hand evidence that this is what caused it but it is a reasonable guess.  If you don't understand clone semantics it is easy -- especially when using a GUI client -- to specify incorrect paths.

Comment: @Sri My point was more that it should be quite hard to accidentally overwrite a remote repo via the `clone` command. If he hadn't cloned yet, how did he even have a "local" copy? Possibly I'm misunderstanding because of your terminology. `origin` isn't a specific thing, it is just the name Git assigns to the original remote when you clone. If he cloned a local copy, then the original local copy became `origin`. And when you clone, there is only *one* repository to start with, so you *can't* clone in the wrong direction, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @meagar It is possible that my own tenuous grasp of Git is showing :-P  I _do_ understand the peer relationship of Git repositories.  However isn't it true that the repository anointed `origin` is created with the `--bare` switch (and so has no working directory)?  In that respect it _is_ a little different.  All that said I suspect that my fellow developer (somehow) had a local `.git` directory and did a clone operation thereby copying contents from local to remote (what _used to be_) the build reference repository (origin) instead of the other way around (as was intended).

Comment: @Sri `origin` can be any repository. You can rename it to whatever you want, or create a new repo called `origin`. There is literally nothing special about the name except that it is the default remote created for you by git when you clone. The repo you clone from does not have to be bare. Git will not overwrite files during a clone, so it seems more likely that he accidentally copied files overtop of the repo he intended to clone from. There is no way for Git to prevent this; you need to secure access to the file system on which the repo resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of anyway possible other than perhaps some kind of hook?

But what I could recommend further is perhaps making sure that new developers are familiar with git.  Like the person writing the article linked I used git as a kind of svn until i understood it. But after looking through some tutorials and understanding the workflow diagrams I easily got to grips with it.

The biggest mistake is users not understanding.  I know people are going to make mistakes so hopefully someone who is more knowledgeable can provide a fail-safe for you.  But until then, I strongly recommend making sure they know how to use git.
http://osteele.com/archives/2008/05/my-git-workflow